# Tracking unused redux data in React components

Tags: reactjs, redux, single-page-application, saga

I'm looking for a good way to track which props received by a component are not being used and can be safely removed.

In a system I maintain, our client single-page app fetches a large amount of data from some private endpoints in our backend services via redux saga. For most endpoints called, all data received is passed directly to our React components, no filtering applied. We are working to improve the overall system performance, and part of that process involves reducing the amount of data returned by our backend-for-frontend services, given those themselves call a large number of services to compose the returned JSON data, which adds to the overall response time.

Ideally, we want to make sure we only fetch the data we absolutely need and save the server from doing unnecessary calls and data normalization. So far, we've been trimming the backend services data by doing a code inspection; we inspect the returned data for each endpoint, then inspect the front-end code and finally remove the data we identified (as a best guess) as unused. That's proven to be risky and inefficient, frequently we assume some data is unused, then months later find a corner case in which it was actually needed, and have to reverse the work. I'm looking for a smart, automated way to identify unused props in my app. Has anyone else had to work on something like that before? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's an existing library called https://github.com/aholachek/redux-usage-report , which wraps the Redux state in a proxy to identify which pieces of state are actually being used.

That may be sufficiently similar to what you're doing to be helpful, or at least give you some ideas that you can take inspiration from.

Comment: This looks what I've been looking for! Thanks @markerikson, I will give it a try!